# Is there a public NFC Specification for App Clip?

Tags: nfc, apple-appclips

Is there a public specification for the NFC part of the new-for-2020 App Clip?  Is it just an External NDEF record?  I'm asking as someone who is responsible for encoding NFC and RFID chips, not as an app developer.

Comment: NDEF URI records are all that's needed, afaik. App Clip URLs can also be shared as plain text URLs or via QR Codes, so there's no special magic there.

Comment: Best documentation I am aware of: [WWDC 2020 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10146/). At about 9:20 the URL for NFC is mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gereon said they are just URL's and for NFC they would be URI records and the NFC specification for URI's is available at https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-RTD_URI_1.0.pdf

Comment: Thanks, folks.  Good info.